# How to retrieve data from database using textbox and display in listview (or datagridview)

Tags: sql, vb.net, sql-server-2014

I'm relatively new to coding, and i tried to create a cashiering program. Except i can't find anything about this on the web. This is my code so far in case anyone wants to see it:

```
    Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Class CashierMain

            Private m_cn As New SqlConnection
            Private m_DA As SqlDataAdapter
            Private m_CB As SqlCommandBuilder
            Private m_DataTable As New DataTable
            Private m_intRowPosition As Integer = 0

            Private Sub CashierMain_FormClosed(sender As Object, e As FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
                    m_cn.Close()
                    m_cn.Dispose()
            End Sub






            Private Sub CashierMain_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Milk_Convience_ProductsDataSet.ProductIndex' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
                    Me.ProductIndexTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CENSOR_ProductsDataSet.ProductIndex)
                    m_cn.ConnectionString = "CENSOR"
                    'Specify connection string to ADO.NET

                    Me.lblTotal.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.0!,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    CType(0, Byte))

                    Me.lblTotalNum.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.0!,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    CType(0, Byte))

                    Me.lblChange.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.0!,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    CType(0, Byte))

                    Me.lblChangeNum.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 20.0!,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    CType(0, Byte))

                    m_cn.Open()
                    'Establish connection to data source
                    m_DA = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From ProductIndex", m_cn)
                    m_CB = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_DA)
                    'Initialize the Command Builder object
                    m_DA.Fill(m_DataTable)

                    Me.ListView1.View = View.Details
                    Me.ListView1.GridLines = True

                    Dim COM As SqlCommand
                    Dim strQ As String = String.Empty
                    Dim ds As DataSet
                    strQ = "SELECT * FROM ProductIndex"
                    COM = New SqlCommand(strQ, m_cn)
                    ds = New DataSet
                    m_DA.Fill(ds, "Table")
            End Sub

            Private Sub InsertProductInformationToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles InsertProductInformationToolStripMenuItem.Click
                    InsertDatabaseItem.Show()
            End Sub

            Private Sub ExitApplicationToolStripMenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ExitApplicationToolStripMenuItem.Click
                    Application.Exit()
                    End
            End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class InsertDatabaseItem

            Private m_cn As New SqlConnection
            Private m_DA As SqlDataAdapter
            Private m_CB As SqlCommandBuilder
            Private m_DataTable As New DataTable
            Private m_intRowPosition As Integer = 0


            Private Sub InsertDatabaseItem_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
                    m_cn.ConnectionString = "YOUDON'TNEEDTOSEETHIS"

                    m_cn.Open()
                    m_DA = New SqlDataAdapter("Select * From ProductIndex", m_cn)
                    m_CB = New SqlCommandBuilder(m_DA)

            End Sub

            Private Sub btnOK_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnOK.Click
                    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(("INSERT INTO ProductIndex VALUES(" &
                                                                            "@ID," &
                                                                            "@Name," &
                                                                            "@Price," &
                                                                            "@Desc)"), m_cn)

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
                    cmd.Parameters("@ID").Value = txtID.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    cmd.Parameters("@Name").Value = txtName.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Price", SqlDbType.Money)
                    cmd.Parameters("@Price").Value = txtPrice.Text
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Desc", SqlDbType.VarChar)
                    cmd.Parameters("@Desc").Value = txtDesc.Text

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

                    MsgBox("Success!", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "SUCCESS")

                    Me.Hide()

                    txtID.Clear()
                    txtName.Clear()
                    txtPrice.Clear()
                    txtDesc.Clear()

                    m_cn.Close()
                    m_cn.Dispose()
            End Sub


            Private Sub btnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCancel.Click
                    Me.Hide()
            End Sub

    End Class
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you have a question?  Does it work? Is there an error? The insert click should work except the connection is never opened.   Multiple global connections may be a problem down the road too

Comment: As @Plutonix said, You haven't asked a question so we can't help you out. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and amend your post.